# How to iterate through the characters using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string s1, and I want to find all the match string that start with ABC and end with BCD:
Here is what I tried,it will return `['ABCDDDCECCCBCDABCVVVBCD']`

But what I want is: `ABCDDDCECCCBCD, ABCVVVBCD` there are actually two match string sequence
How can I achieve this? 
Thanks!!

```
   s1='AABCDDDCECCCBCDABCVVVBCD'
    t1 ='ABC.*BCD'
    t2 = 'ABC.*CEC'
```

I want to get all the string that match to the condition of start from ABD end in BCD and start from ABC and in CEC.
So the expected result is `ABCDDDCEC, ABCVVVBCD` it should not return ABCDDDCECCCBCD

Comment: Your regular expression will try to match as much characters as possible `.*` until the end of the string `$`. Which is the whole string, except the first character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your regex.

- You have `.*` which captures everything greedily and will as much as it can which will exhaust any of the sequences of `ABCsomethingBCD`
- You have `$` end of string anchor which forces the string to match till end of line.

You can use this regex, where match starts from `ABC` then captures as less as it can by non-greedy regex `.*?` then matches `BCD` and since there is no `$` character it doesn't get forced to match till end of line. Notice, even if you change `.*` to `.*?` and don't remove `$` from the regex, you will still get only one match till end of line and that's because `.*?` is forced to match till end of line as there is `$` character present in regex. Fixing that makes the behavior as expected.

```
ABC.*?BCD
```

Python demo,

```
import re

s1='AABCDDDCECCCBCDABCVVVBCD'
t1 ='ABC.*?BCD'
re.findall(t1,s1)
```

Prints,

```
['ABCDDDCECCCBCD', 'ABCVVVBCD']
```

In case, your string is `AABCDDDCECCCABCVVVBCD` and you don't want to match the second `ABC` in the string till `BCD`, you can use this **[tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html)** based regex,

```
ABC(?:(?!ABC).)*BCD
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJIVDU/1)**

**Edit 2:**
For given string as `AABCDDDCECCCABCVVVBCD` you want to get these two matches as per your post edit,

```
ABCDDDCEC and ABCVVVBCD
```

You can use this regex,

```
ABC.*?(?:CEC|BCD)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJIVDU/2)**

Comment: Thank you! What is my string is s1='AABCDDDCECCCABCVVVBCD'

Comment: Then it will start from first occurrence of `ABC` which happens to be from second character and will match till end of line as `BCD` is only present at the end. Do you instead want to match the second `ABC` till last `BCD` instead of first one? I can do that easily if you need that.

Comment: Yes, please. Like if there is another condition need to find ABC.*CEC, how can I get ABCDDDCEC and then continue to search for ABCVVVBCD. Which means it must start from ABC, but if it matches at the end of CEC or BCD, it will turn back the value, and continue to search for the next matching value.

Comment: I am feeling like you are wanting overlapping matches. Is that so? Can you show me a string and list the expected matches from it?

Comment: I got your matches. Updating my answer with the regex for same. Few moments please :)

Comment: @ShinYuWu: Edited my post for your edited requirements. Please see and let me know if that's the thing you wanted.